# How can I upload a DB to Heroku

Tags: database, git, heroku, migrate

I have a shared heroku app, now I wan't to create a test app also in heroku with the same code, so I've created a new app, ok, the thing is that for the app to work it needs a database, so I'm trying to upload my local DB but don't know how to.

Can anyone tell me what do I have to type in my command line so I can get my local DB uploaded?

Thanks

Ps: The app uses Django

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should restore database from a url, see [heroku import doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import):

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE 'http://f.cl.l...3z18/mydb.dump'
```

**Edit:**

The `pgbackups` addon has been [deprecated](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups). The process is now built in to the CLI tools. More details [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups). The new method looks like this:

```
heroku pg:backups restore 'http://f.cl.l...3z18/mydb.dump' DATABASE
```

Comment: Ok, that seems to be the answer, just one more thing, How do I create or obtain the URL?

Comment: Do you have several ways: as doc say you can use Amazon S3 or CloudApp that is the fast way, also you can share it via drop box or open a port in your home router and let heroku to take file from your home machine.

Comment: this really is a horrible approach when dealing with sensitive data ...

Comment: @Pinna_be , database url may be an httpS resouce (with S = Secure )

Answer (score 5):

@danihp's answer is a good one - it is exactly what [the documentation recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#export).

BUT it requires posting the file in some awkward place like S3.

However, as the OP asks - how can we do this without having to push the database dump to someplace awkward like S3?

The most convenient answer I've been able to find (mentioned in @danihp's comment) is to use dropbox.

In detail (not described in danihp's comment):

Simply

- put the dump file into your "Public" dropbox folder
- right click and choose "Copy Public Link"
- Paste the url you just copied into the command:

  ```
  heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE_URL "<paste link here>"
  ```

If you don't want to put the dump file in your "Public" folder, then you need to do one more step.

You need to

- put is in some other dropbox folder
- right click, and chose "share Dropbox Link"
- paste the link into a browser, which will show you the dump file page
- right click the "download" button and copy the URL.
- paste *that* URL into the command.

HTH.