# Migrate Django development database (.sql3) to Heroku

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql, amazon-s3, migrate

How does one migrate their Django .sql3 development database to heroku?

[image: django project with important database highlighted that must be migrated]

Per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500631/how-can-i-upload-a-db-to-heroku), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508898/how-can-i-import-a-sql-file-into-my-heroku-postgres-database) I tried: `heroku pg:psql --app sblic < database.sql3` but my Django admin shows no new uploads (even after syncdb/migrate/ or collectstatic

Comment: Umm: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/UploadingObjectsintoAmazonS3.html

Comment: The easiest way to move your database and code up to Heroku is just via a git push.

Comment: Your question shows a SQLite3 database. How is that related to an example that shows how to push a Postgres database? I think you need to re-state your question.

Comment: @Brandon In Heroku the default database is Postgres, using django on local environment the default is SQLite3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps there may be a way to directly upload an sql3 file to Heroku, but I went with the path of clearest certainty (convert local sql3 db to postgre db and [upload a dump of postgre db to Heroku via pgbackups tool](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)):

1. [Create a dump of your sql3 database as a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034910/whats-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-django-db-from-sqlite-to-mysql)
2. With PostgreSql installed and with its `bin` directory in the `Path` environment variable, [create a postgre user and database](http://djangogirls.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-extensions/content/optional_postgresql_installation/README.html) (or just plan on using your initial super user account created upon installing postgresql)
3. Update your `settings.py` with a [reference to your newly created postgre database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394331/how-to-setup-postgresql-database-in-django) (note, `'HOST'` may need to be set as `'localhost'`, `'user'` is your postgre user login)
4. run `python manage.py syncdb` to initiate your new postgre db
5. Optional: if necessary, [truncate your postgre db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076928/switching-django-project-from-sqlite3-backend-to-postgresql-failes-when-loading) of contenttypes
6. [load your dump from step 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034910/whats-the-best-way-to-migrate-a-django-db-from-sqlite-to-mysql) (if you have fixture issues, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853796/problems-with-contenttypes-when-loading-a-fixture-in-django))
7. Now you have a working postgre local db. [To migrate, first create a postgre dump](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#create-dump-file)
8. Post your postgre dump somewhere accessible by URL (such as drop box or amazon s3 as suggested in previous link).
9. Perform [pgbackups restore command, referencing your dump url](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import-to-heroku-postgres)
10. Your heroku app should now reference the contents of your local db.

Comment: This always gives fixture error. even after adding arguments like `--natural-foreign --natural-primary` while dumping. @DanielRoseman sir do you know the fix ? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku command line tool uses the `psql` binary. You have to install PostgreSQL on your local development machine to have psql available. From the (documentation)[https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql]:

> You must have PostgreSQL installed on your system to use heroku pg:psql.

You can in fact keep using your SQLite database with Heroku, but this is not recommended as it will be rewritten with your local copy if you re-deploy it to another dyno. Migrating the data to psql is recommended as described at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Comment: excellent, but I have a .sql3 database so I'll need to convert to postgres first...